# Ubuntu 18.04 not recognizing my graphics card (I think)?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, display-resolution

I have a problem with my Ubuntu being in a low resolution and only being able to use one screen out of my two. The resolution is 1024x768 so I guess my graphics card is not being recognized by ubuntu.

My graphics card is: Nvidia MSI GeForce RTX 2070 8GB

Running sudo lshw -C video gives me the following:

```
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: NVIDIA Corporation
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
```

Both screens work fine in windows (I have dual boot ubuntu and windows 10).

Anyone got any idea why this is?

Comment: What is the output of `lspci -v | grep NVIDIA`

Comment: I can test in a while, but I guess it would be the same as above

Comment: The output is: 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f02 (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10f9 (rev a1)
01:00.2 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1ada (rev a1) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
01:00.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1adb (rev a1)